# Random Variable and Chebyshev's Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Give an example of a random variable $X$ and $α > 0$ such that $P(X ≥ α) > \frac{E[X]}{α}$.

I am confused by this problem. I know Chebyshev's Inequality satisfies the inverse of this statement so I do not understand how any variable can satisfy these conditions given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chebyshev gives opposite inequality for non-negative random variables. For a counterexample take any random variable with mean $0$ such that $P(X \geq \alpha) \neq 0$ for some $\alpha >0$. In fact you can take any non-constant random variable with mean $0$ and choose appropriate $\alpha$. Example: $X=\pm 1$ with probability $\frac 1 2$ each and $\alpha =\frac 1 2$.

Comment: Is there an example of a continuous random variable satisfying the conditions?

Comment: Surely. Let $X$ be a standard normal random varible and $\alpha$ be any positive number.